# What are 'name' and 'symbol' in MySQL indexes?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, unique, primary-key

Primary Key definitions can have a optional symbol value, while Uniques can have both symbol and name. What are these, and what is their differences? And what is best practices to use them?

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. Can you give the link to the source where you found this?

Comment: Thank you @shanmuga, You can find it on MySQL documentation, for example in [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html), under `create_definition`.

Comment: "too broad"??  What do you mean??  Is two _good_ answers that say practically the same thing, and that cover what was asked, "too many possible answerers"?  Voting to reopen.

Comment: @user5483434 - I'm griping at the 5 people who voted to Close [put on hold] this thread.

Comment: @RickJames, Oh! Right... I must say that freedom and democracy is good, but can lead to stupid governments, too ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`symbol` is the name of the constraint. Should you later need to drop, disable or re-enable the constraint you identify it to the system using this symbol.

`index_name` is the name of an index created using `CREATE INDEX` which is to be used to enforce the `UNIQUE` constraint. (An index is a database object which is separate from the table it indexes.) If you do *not* specify the name of an existing index, the system will generate an index for you, and if you later disable the constraint the index will automatically be dropped and must be recreated when the constraint is re-enabled. If you *do* specify an existing index, it will *not* be dropped and recreated with the constraint, thus saving considerable time and processing power. Some other platforms also allow you to specify an existing index to enforce a Primary Key.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Darwin has the perfect answer for you. I am just going to add examples to demonstrate symbol and how you can use it. I recommended using symbol names on both unique and primary keys. Use index name on indexes. More to come.

**Doc**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html shows:

```
create_definition:
    col_name column_definition
  | [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] PRIMARY KEY [index_type] (index_col_name,...)
      [index_option] ...
  | {INDEX|KEY} [index_name] [index_type] (index_col_name,...)
      [index_option] ...
  | [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] UNIQUE [INDEX|KEY]
      [index_name] [index_type] (index_col_name,...)
      [index_option] ...
```

**Constraint**

Notice that PRIMARY and UNIQUE keys are constraints whereas a regular index/key doesn't have the keyword `CONSTRAINT`.

**Symbol**

So what's symbol all about? It's just a name given to the primary key, unique key, index etc. Let's take an example:

```
create table test1 (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    national_id varchar(50) not null,
    firstname varchar(50) not null,
    lastname varchar(50) not null,
    age int not null,
    constraint pk_test1_id primary key (id),
    constraint uq_test1_national_id unique key (national_id),
    index idx_test1_age (age)
);
```

Primary key's symbol/name is `pk_test1_id`. Unique key's symbol/name is `uq_test1_national_id` and index's symbol/name is `idx_test1_age`.

** Where can I see symbol or index name?**

```
show index from test1;

| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | ...
| test1 | 0 | PRIMARY ...
| test1 | 0 | uq_test1_national_id ...
| test1 | 1 | idx_test1_age ...
```

When displaying indexes, you can see that non_unique column indicates whether the key is unique or non-unique. Unique key'ed column can contain null and cannot contain duplicate information. Primary key'ed column cannot contain null and cannot contain duplicate information. Key_name shows PRIMARY instead of the symbol.

**Where can I see keys across all tables, if needed?**

```
select column_name, column_key 
from information_schema.`COLUMNS` 
where table_name = 'test1'

| column_name | column_key | 
| id | PRI | 
| national_id | UNI | 
...
| age | MUL |
```

Notice that information_schema.columns also shows similar information but does not describe the name of the key.

**Use symbol and index name to drop**

In unique key if symbol and index names are given, index name should be used to drop the unique key.

Symbols are helpful when dropping an index and reviewing table's metadata. A wisely chosen constraint or index symbol/name can be quite helpful to the reader when they display `show create table test1` or `show index from test1` etc.

```
-- drop unique key using its symbol
alter table test1 drop index uq_test1_national_id;

-- drop the primary key; since primary key was on auto_increment and that
-- auto_increment should be a key, I am forcing an index on id before
-- removing primary key
create index idx_test1_id on test1 (id);
alter table test1 drop primary key;

-- drop index using its symbol/name
alter table test1 drop index idx_test1_age;
```

**Consistency with symbol name; therefore I recommend**

Also note that if, during creation of table, we had specified:

```
constraint uq_test1_national_id unique key uq_my_own_name (national_id),
```

Then `show index from test1` will use uq_my_own_name. `alter table ... drop index` will also need `uq_my_own_name`. Therefore, for unique keys I propose to use only the symbol and not the index_name.

Comment: Is there any case in MySql where both `symbol` and `index_name` are useful?

Comment: I don't find any use for both. For any constraint (e.g. PK, UK or FK) I just use symbol and for index I use index_name since index don't have a symbol name.

Comment: To be consistent won't it be better to use index_name for both constraint as well as index. And thus having a separate symbol is obsolete. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Primary key does not have index_name. Index doesn't have symbol name. Unique key has both. So choosing becomes difficult. It's best to choose symbol and/or index_name and just stay consistent with its use.